# Failed to build fastavro

Tags: pip, build, fastavro

I am trying to install a package (Cohere package). When I try to install it, I get an error message saying:

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastavro Failed to build fastavro
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastavro, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

So I tried to install fastavro manually and I got the same error:

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastavro, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

What I tried:

I first tried to install  using pip install fastavro. I also tried:

> pip install fastavro --prefer-binary

That installed it but when I try to run commands, I get the same error as above.

I also tried:

> conda install fastavro -c conda-forge

I then got a message from conda where it would delete some packages and add new ones (?). Not sure why it was doing that - it also said conda would downgrade which did not make sense to me.

Also, brew install fastavro does not work either - it does not seem to be a package in home brew.

Comment: Do you have more output from the build failure? What OS and python version are you using? Also, when you say "That installed it but when I try to run commands, I get the same error as above" what does that mean? It was able to install but then continued to give errors about installing?